# How to use multiple AdMob unit ids in one android manifest file

Tags: admob, android-manifest, godot

I have been trying to add ads in my game using admob but i have hit a wall. I have been trying to use multiple ad units in my app but i keep getting errors. Here are my problems:

1. In the android manifest file i have added:
   `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917"/>`
   i am a little confused on what i should put in "APPLICATION_ID". any help?
2. I have multiple ad units and i want to use both intertisial and rewarded ads in my game but it gives me an error if i try to add two tags saying that "com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" is duplicated.
   I have been trying for days and cant figure it out.

I tried to add two meta data tags  but to no avail. I dont know how to add two add units in my app and am a beginner in android development so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add one time this meta-data tag in your manifest like this**

[image]

**And put your ad ids in your string file like this**

[image]

**And use like this**

[image]